# Java Spring MVC ExecuteCommand?

Tags: java, spring

Hi is there any way to executeCommand in linux terminal via spring ? I want simple example like

```
ping google.com
```

I tried using example from here http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/ but I cant create object

```
ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();
```

Comment: Why can't you create it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need spring for that :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")
```

will do as well. But this is discouraged, as java runs in a sandbox, and you may not be granted the access of all commands for (obvious) security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the class name in that example. Java requires that `public` top level class names match the class name itself.

```
public class ExecuteShellCommand {
```